# Device timed out on boot after enabling lvmcache

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, ssd

I added an mSATA drive to my laptop and used it as an lvmcache for the LVM stored on my (spinning) hard drive.  This LVM contains `/home` (as well as `/var`, `/opt` and `/usr`).

Upon booting (with kernel 4.9.8-1), it takes a while and I see the following:

```
(1 of 2) A start job is running for device dev-LVM-home.device (39sec / 1min 29sec)
(2 of 2) A stop job is running for LVM2 PV scan on device 8:35 (39sec / 1min 29sec)
```

After that minute and a half, I see:

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-LVM-home.device.
[ DEPEND ] Dependency failed for /home.
[ DEPEND ] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[ DEPEND ] Dependency failed for File System check on /dev/LVM/home.
```

I then get the "you are in emergency mode" prompt.  Pressing ctrl-d allows the laptop to boot up properly and /home (and its cache) is mounted correctly!

How do I fix this?  How do I get it to correctly mount /home on boot?

In my `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`, I have:

```
HOOKS="base systemd plymouth autodetect block sd-lvm2 filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

Comment: Maybe [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1423796/comments/6) could help?

Comment: That may help point me in the right direction.  There may be some hook I'm missing to allow Arch Linux to initialize the cache on bootup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution!  Not sure why I didn't think of this before.

In `/etc/fstab`, I had the `/usr` partition mounted *after* `/home`, that was causing the issue here.

Mounting `/usr` right after `/` (and thus ***before*** `/home`), fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM#LVM_Cache_.28lvmcache.29) troubleshooting suggest

The `use_lvmetad = 1` must be set in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`. This is the default now - if you have a `lvm.conf.pacnew` file, you must merge this change.

Comment: That could be it!  I don't know what values are set in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` nor whether I have a `lvm.conf.pacnew` file (or any other `*.pacnew* files for that mater).  I'll have to check this and see if it'll fix it.

Comment: I checked the file and `use_lvmetad = 1` is already set.